# How to estimate regression coefficients if the errors are t-distributed?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, assumptions, t-distribution

I estimated the linear regression using ols but the errors turned out to be t-distributed with df=3 according to q-q plot, I already know that gauss-markov theorem still assume the coefficients to be BLUE if errors are non normal , but the inference would not be reliable and therefore the significance of the variables cannot be determined.

Comment: Is estimation or inference your goal? As you point out, the OLS estimator does not make use of the error distribution and hence would be the same, and would here also still be a consistent quasi MLE for the true parameter vector.

Comment: Inference, I am actually trying to examine the significance of the indep variables on the dependent variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can I rely on p-values generated by OLS to examine the significance of the variables if the errors are t-distributed ? if no what are the alternative solutions ?

Comment: The fact that OLS are BLUE does not justify using OLS. The restriction to estimators that are linear functions of the data and unbiased rules out all the interesting and often better estimators, like MLEs. The BLUE property, in essence, states the OLS is the biggest fish in a tiny puddle.